# Is it possible to create a lookAheadBuffer from a java.util.Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to build a look ahead buffer based on the current state of a java.util.Scanner.  By this I mean if you think of a Scanner as a conveyer belt that delivers 'words' the 'current state' of the Scanner would be the words remaining on the conveyer belt.

I thought I could do this by constructing another, temporary Scanner that held the current state of the original scanner.  I could then use getNext() to populate the look ahead buffer from the temporary scanner and not affect the state of the original scanner.

Unfortunately, there is no constructor or method that provides the current state of the original scanner as I need it.

Is it possible to create a look Ahead Buffer from the current state of a Scanner?

Comment: I suggest you read the Scanner once.  It is designed to interact with users amongst other things and I doubt you want to ask the user what they want to type before they type it.

Comment: I agree with Peter: Scanner consumes input streams, and it will permanently advance the state of an underlying stream if it calls a bulk read to fill its own internal buffer.  I don't see how this idea can (reasonably) work.

Comment: May be I did not make my purpose clear.  I'm constructing a Scanner from a document not a stream.  I need to look ahead of the current scanner position but not change the state of the original scanner, i.e. not call getNext() on the original scanner.

Comment: @user903724 In some cases the Scanner will not have a next value, what is supposed to happen then?

Comment: That is actually the purpose of this exercise.  To look ahead for:

Comment: Sorry, hit the return key.  The purpose of this exercise is to locate patterns in the document.  By looking ahead you can determine a couple of things:  1.  If the pattern is in the document and 2. if the pattern is longer than the document and can't possibly be in the document.

Comment: If you need to know how many tokens are still in the stream -- Scanner doesn't offer that functionality: its hasNext or getNext. You _could_ implement a wrapper around a scanner which buffers N tokens. If you want to recognize patterns of tokens in a document, that's what a parser is for. Look into JavaCC or ANTLR.

Answer (score 0):

As most replies made it clear, Scanner has no look ahead capabilities.  In case anyone is interested here is how I did it.  These three methods are in a class called ScannableDocument.

```
    /**
     * Return the next word in the document.  Just a wrapper for Scanner and look ahead buffer methods.
     * The caller does not have to call hasNext().  
     * The caller does have to catch DocumentExhaustedException.
     * @return next word from scanner
     * @throws DocumentExhaustedException
     */
public String getNextWord() throws DocumentExhaustedException {

        // if the lookAheadBuffer is not empty, return its first element (fifo queue) instead of moving the scanner
        if ( !lookAheadBuffer.isEmpty()) {
            return lookAheadBuffer.removeFirst() ;
        } else {
            if ( scanner.hasNext()) {
                return scanner.next();
            } else {
                throw new DocumentExhaustedException("ScannableDocument.getNextWord()") ;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Move numWords off of the conveyer.  
     * @param numWords
     * @throws DocumentExhaustedException
     */
    public void advanceConveyer ( int numWords ) throws DocumentExhaustedException {
        for ( int word=1; word<=numWords ; word++) {
            getNextWord() ;
        }
    }


    /**
     * The look ahead buffer is used to recognize patterns in the document that start with the 'current' word
     * The patterns come from a dictionary.  The look ahead buffer is loaded
     * with dictionaryEntry.size() words to enable a String comparison.

     * @param numWords
     */
    public void loadLookAheadBuffer ( int numWords )  throws DocumentExhaustedException  {

        if ( lookAheadBuffer.size() >= numWords) return ; // Already have enough words in the buffer

        for ( int i=1; i<=(numWords-lookAheadBuffer.size()) ; i++ ) {
            if ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
                lookAheadBuffer.add ( scanner.next()) ;
            } else {
                throw new DocumentExhaustedException("ScannableDocument.loadLookAheadBuffer()") ;
            }
        }
    }
```